# Firebase Dynamic Link Query Parameters are always empty

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

Hi I am new to Firebase Dynamic Links and I don't know how to add Query Parameters to my Dynamic links.

I am calling https://{myAppName}.page.link/raffle/?id=cdfufuwhg

This is the Dynamic Link i configured in the Console: https://{myAppName}.page.link/raffle

In my Flutter Application I process the link like this:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
        print("Debug 1");
        print(dynamicLink.link.toString());
        print(dynamicLink.link.queryParameters);
    if (dynamicLink.link.queryParameters.containsKey("id")) {
      print("Debug 2");
      String id = dynamicLink.link.queryParameters["id"];
      print(id);
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => RaffleDetails(),
          settings: RouteSettings(arguments: id),
        ),
      );
    }
  });
```

However, this is what the console Returns:

```
Debug 1
https://{myAppName}.page.link/raffle
{} <- This is where my Query params should be
```

Is this information enough for you to help me or do you need more info?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?